# Thread safe events with WinForms GUI Control

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, delegates

I know GUI components cannot be used from different threads. So you normally do a method which check `InvokeRequired`, then call `Invoke` etc. But this is a lot of code. Is any way to do something like that: `MyEvent += myDelegate` and this myDelegate will be executed from thread where it was assigned? 
And why Invoke method is available only from `Control` class? Only idea I have is to make own method like AddDelegate (delegate.. , Control c) or something like that.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Well, yes - why the 'InvokeRequired' call?  Of course it's required, so why check?  On the matter of the Control target - I'm guessing that the Control class and descendants can handle messages Sent/Posted to them.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid such repeatitive code, I usually create a class to isolate this logic. When application is starting up, I initialize this class and use it throughout the application. The advantage is it can be used outside of Controls.

```
public static class UI
{
    private static Control internalControl;

    public static void Initialize(Control control)
    {
        internalControl = control;
    }

    public static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        if (internalControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            internalControl.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize when main Form is initialized:

```
UI.Initialize(this);
```

Usage:

```
UI.Invoke(() => { this.Text = "Test"; });
```

Comment: So if i have many UserControls, then i need to initialize the class in every UserControl?

Answer (score 2):

I used a rather simple method:

```
private void execThreadSafeMethod(Control ctrl)
{
     MethodInvoker method = (MethodInvoker) delegate
     {
         //Do something that you always wanted to do :)
     }
     if(ctrl.InvokeRequired == true)
     {
          ctrl.Invoke(method);
     }
     {
          method.Invoke();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .Net 4?  If so you can use Asynchronous Tasks.

You would create a TaskScheduler from the synchronisation context of the main thread where the controls were created.

```
var uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Then you could use this in any method running on a background thread to update any control on the main thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => { MessageBox.Show("Message from separate thread.") }, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    uiTaskScheduler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kept waiting to find my method but I don't see it (hope I read the question right)

This is how I handle Invokes in separate threads:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { /*whatever I need done*/ });
```

This is nice because you can keep your code where it is applicable and not jump around

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
    //here is some code I need to run on the main thread
    //usually making a label visible or some other bs
    //might want to resize my form or update a list box, who knows
});
```